# Why does Firefox delay the download button?

Tags: web, download, firefox

When you download a file with Firefox, there is a delay for a few seconds before the button to save the file becomes enabled.

What's the motivation for this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## This is a security feature.

It is to prevent unintended downloads. If the user is attempting to interact with the webpage, for instance typing some prescribed text or double-clicking somewhere, without a delay, it would be possible for malicious websites to unexpectedly prompt for a download, and unintentionally be given approval by the user.

For more information, see [this full explanation](http://www.squarefree.com/2004/07/01/race-conditions-in-security-dialogs/) detailed by Jesse Ruderman who worked for Mozilla on the security team for quite some time, as well as [a workaround](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1176544) to disable this security feature, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save something that's not downloading so Firefox goes through all the handshaking protocols to make sure there is something to download before giving you that option.

Comment: Or at least it *used* to go through all the handshaking. Now it just waves from a safe distance.

Comment: @musefan What does that mean?

Comment: @maxathousand: Nothing of substance. Handshakes, coronavirus, etc.

Comment: @musefan Hahha, got it now.